# I would like comments on an approch to wrap widgets in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget, wrapper

When using jQueryUi widgets (dialog, datepicker etc) I always wonder if there would be better to wrap the widgets in some kind of wrapper class. Here is one way to do this, but I'm not sure if this is good practice.

**Please comment**

**CODE**

Small plugin for $ that wraps 'dialog'.

```
//Widget Wrapper plugin POC.
//Should be extended to support all Methods on all Widgets in jQueryUI   
(function ($) {
    $.fn.ww = function (uiWidgetName, options) {
    if (this.length == 1) {
        return new wrappers[uiWidgetName](this[0], options);
    }
}


var wrappers= {};

wrappers.dialog = function (element, options) {
    var theWidget = $(element);
    theWidget.dialog(options);

    this.open = function () {
        theWidget.dialog('open');
    }
    this.close = function () {
        theWidget.dialog('close');
    }
  }

} (jQuery))
```

This could be used like this

```
var a = $("#WrapperTest").ww('dialog',{ autoOpen: false });            
a.open();
```

Comment: whats the benefit of the wrapper class?  How does it make the code simpler to use or easier to understand?

Comment: because u don't have to do the $("#WrapperTest").dialog('???') every time you would like to access something in then dialog.

Comment: but then you can use `var $myDialog = $("#your_dialog").dialog();` and then use `$myDialog` ?

Comment: u could, but then u must do $myDialog.dialog('open')

Comment: what is the problem with `$myDialog.dialog('open');`?? This allows you to apply multiple widgets to the same element and keep their namespaces/data separate.  An example is if you wanted something to be draggable, droppable, and resizeable.  Let's say when you drop it, you want to disable droppable, and enable resizeable.  These use the same function call (enable/disable), so if you combine their namespaces, you will likely get undesired results.  Also note, you should almost never use the 'new' operator in JS. Can end up clobbering your global namespace if it is used incorrectly.

Comment: To clarify, instead of like classical languages where you define a class and use 'new' for new objects, in JS, you should normally write a function that returns an object for your inheritance and classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually, the functions added to the `$.fn` namespace by jQuery UI (`$.fn.dialog()` in your case) are *already* wrappers around each widget's methods.

It looks like you want to implement some kind of "reverse-wrapper" around the existing `dialog()` wrapper in order to be able to access the widget's methods directly. Adding another layer of overhead is not necessary, as you only have to invoke the widget's constructor directly, specifying the widget options and the target element:

```
var dialogWidget = new $.ui.dialog({
    autoOpen: false
}, $("#WrapperTest")[0]);
```

Then you can do things like:

```
dialogWidget.open();
dialogWidget.close();
dialogWidget.option("autoOpen", !dialogWidget.option("autoOpen"));
// and so on.
```

If you have created a dialog the "usual" way (through `$.fn.dialog()`) and you want to to obtain a reference to its widget instance further down the line, you can fetch it from the element's [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) using the widget's name as the key:

```
$("#WrapperTest").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});

var dialogWidget = $("#WrapperTest").data("dialog");
dialogWidget.open();
```

You can test the code above in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aL5B9/).

***Update:*** From jQuery UI 1.9 onwards, [the `data()` key becomes the widget's fully qualified name, with dots replaced by dashes](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys). Therefore, the code above becomes:

```
var dialogWidget = $("#WrapperTest").data("ui-dialog");
dialogWidget.open();
```

Using the unqualified name is still supported in 1.9 but is deprecated, and support will be dropped in 1.10.